# np.array2string misreporting values?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter, precision

I am using numpy and numpy.array2string to probe effects of small changes and numerical stability.  I am baffled by the following exercise:

```
<Get vector data through prior code>
print(data.shape)
print(data.dtype)
variance = np.var(data)
print(variance.dtype)
print(variance)
print(np.array2string(variance, suppress_small=True,formatter={'float': '{: 8.55f}'.format}))
```

Which gives as output:

```
torch.Size([1, 64])  # shape of the data
torch.float32        # dtype of the data
float32              # dtype of the variance result
37166410.0
37166408.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This makes me crosseyed:  The array2string isn't just reformatting the value with a (patently absurd) number of digits, it seems to be changing the value itself well above the point where round off errors should matter.  (It doesn't *seem* to be the formatter, as I can remove that and still see changed values.)

A float32 can easily represent either of those integer values directly.
What am I not understanding here?  Please reaffirm my faith in objective reality.

*UPDATE:* No float32 cannot exactly represent 37166410.0, and I need reading glasses.

Comment: *"A float32 can easily represent either of those integer values directly."* No, it can't.  The spacing between the exactly representable values near 37166410 is *4*.  That might give you a hint about what is going on.

Comment: By the way, you might question your faith in objective reality even more if you print `variance + 1`. :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: When `repr(np.float32(37166411))` returns `37166412.0` it helps the user see that 37166412.0 is representable as a float32, but 37166411 is not. But `repr(np.float32(37166410))` returns `37166410.0` even though it appears 37166410 is not exactly representable as a float32. Is that a bug?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Also, `repr(np.nextafter(37166405, np.inf, dtype='float32'))` returns `'37166410.0'`, which seems to imply 37166410.0 is representable as a float32, but numerically it seems to behave as 37166408.0. Shouldn't the repr be returning 37166408?

Comment: *"Is that a bug?"*  I don't know--I've been wondering the same thing.   The jumps in the displayed values in an array such as `np.array(range(37166390, 37166430), dtype=np.float32)` are surprising to me.  Ping @MarkDickinson!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser One source of difficulties is my eyesight, which caused me to think the number was an order of magnitude lower than it actually is (which would be exactly representable.)  As soon as I figure out a graceful edit to the original post I will make one.   I still don't understand *exactly* what is going on here.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Looks as though this is a consequence of the new (in 1.14) shortest-string repr. It makes more sense if you think in scientific notation: the string `3716641e+1` needs 7 significant digits, and is rounds to the correct `float32` value under the usual round-ties-to-even rounding mode. The string `37166408e+0` needs 8 significant digits, so the shorter version is preferred. And then the formatting of those 7 digits ends up padding with a bogus zero. When Python implemented shortest-string based repr, we moved the thresholds for scientific notation exactly to avoid this issue.

Comment: So IOW, it's not exactly *wrong*, in that the guarantee that the `repr` roundtrips back to the correct value is still there (`x = np.float32(37166408); np.float32(repr(x)) == x` gives `True`). But it's certainly misleading.